# How would I minus one month from the previous month?

Tags: sql, data-analysis

Currently the my database is setup, in order to get a full picture of the month to date (MTD) value, you have to use year to date (YTD) - the previous month year to date (YTD) to get the values for the current month.

Math Example of trying to get October's Month to date (MTD) Value: October YTD - September YTD

Currently I have the query setup (below) to pull in current period (Table A) and then Prior period (Table B) which is 1 minus the current period identifier.

Table A is the current YTD value WHEREAS Table B is always one month behind table A.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.pe, 
            a.penum AS 'Current Period',
            sum(a.hwaytd) AS 'AHoursWorked', 
            b.penum AS 'Previous Period', 
            sum(b.hwaytd) AS 'BhoursWorked'
   
FROM stageElite.dbo.df_dwtkmat a
JOIN stageElite.dbo.df_dwtkmat b on b.matter = a.matter and a.watty = b.watty and b.penum = a.penum-1  

WHERE a.matter = '001153.1510'

GROUP BY b.pe, b.penum, a.penum
ORDER BY a.penum DESC
```

Why is the query wrong for some months? It starts to mess up in periods 0619 (june 2019) where the numbers are off, but from 0719- 1219, the months are accurate. See picture. Accurate values are green. Red values are wrong.

[image]

```
pe    | a.penum | AHoursWorked | b.pe   | b.penum | BHours Worked
------------------------------------------------------------
 1219 |   371   |    5,844     |  1119  |  370    |   8,542
 1119 |   370   |    8,542     |  1019  |  369    |   8382.5
 1019 |   369   |    0         |  NULL  |  NULL   |   NULL
 1019 |   369   |    8,382     |  0919  |  368    |   8,264.75
 0919 |   368   |    0.5       |  NULL  |  NULL   |   NULL
 0919 |   368   |    8,264     |  0819  |  367    |   8,103.75
```

Comment: Why have you tagged 3 completely different RDBMS? The SQL above clearly looks like SQL Server, however, I have removed all 3 tags. Please retag the correct RDBMS and **only** the correct RDBMS.

Comment: Having a [mcve] would be really helpful here.

Comment: What's the database? Looks like SQL Server or Sybase.

Answer (score 0):

Your implicit `INNER JOIN` is only returning rows where `a.watty` matches `b.watty`. This is effectively applying a filter that is having an impact on your aggregated results.

Consider the following simplified table:

```
 penum | watty | hwaytd
------------------------
   1   |   1   |   5
   1   |   2   |   5
   2   |   1   |   5
   2   |   2   |   5
   3   |   1   |   5
```

This query:

```
SELECT a.penum AS APenum, SUM(a.hwaytd) AS AHoursWorked,
       b.penum AS BPenum, SUM(b.hwaytd) AS BHoursWorked
FROM df_dwtkmat a
INNER JOIN df_dwtkmat b ON b.watty = a.watty AND b.penum = a.penum - 1
GROUP BY a.penum, b.penum
```

Will produce this result, notice that `HoursWorked` do not match for `Penum` = 2:

```
 APenum | AHoursWorked | BPenum | BHoursWorked
-----------------------------------------------
   2    |      10      |   1    |      10
   3    |      5       |   2    |      5
```

Removing the filter is not a solution by itself, as this will create a many to many relationship and your aggregations will multiply. One potential solution is to do the aggregation in steps.

```
SELECT a.penum AS APenum, a.HoursWorked AS AHoursWorked,
       b.penum AS BPenum, b.HoursWorked AS BHoursWorked
FROM (SELECT penum, SUM(hwaytd) AS HoursWorked
      FROM df_dwtkmat
      GROUP BY penum) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT penum, SUM(hwaytd) AS HoursWorked
           FROM df_dwtkmat
           GROUP BY penum) b ON b.penum = a.penum - 1
```

Comment: @Ciara Let's just pick a month, say October. I'm not sure what a `watty` is but let's say it's an employee. The `a` side is going to sum all the hours worked by all employees in October. The `b` side is going to sum all the hours worked in September by employees who worked in October. If an employee was let go, quit, or took vacation for the entire month of October their hours would not appear in `b`.

Comment: I attached sample data. WAIT. I think I get it. Would the same logic be true for employees who did work in October and NOT in September -- which is why it is breaking it out because the employee worked one month and not the other?

Comment: @Ciara if you're using an `INNER JOIN` employees will have to work both months to be counted. So in October's row an employee will have to work in October and September to have their hours counted, and in September's row an employee will need to work in September and August to be counted.